# YAML syntax issue

Tags: yaml

I am new to YAML, only know JSON and XML formats

I have this .yml configuration for TravisCI and it has a some weird syntax error and I cannot figure out how to fix it.

Originally I had this, and everything was fine:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '7'
  - '6'
  - '5'
  - '4'
script: 'npm install istanbul && node cli.js --coverage test/testsrc/es5-es6/a.js'
after_script: 'npm install coveralls && cat coverage/lcov.info | ./node_modules/.bin/coveralls'
notifications:
  email: false
  slack:
    rooms:
      - sumanjs:gvauyHhXXXXXpV5v8LlQOAcI#general
```

But I read that we need to get some C++ libraries available in the container, so I had to add some some stuff to the .yml file according to these instructions:

> https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs#Node.js-v4-(or-io.js-v3)-compiler-requirements

So now I have this, which is invalid, but I have no idea why:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '7':
   env:
      - CXX=g++-4.8
    addons:
      apt:
        sources:
          - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
        packages:
          - g++-4.8
  - '6':
   env:
      - CXX=g++-4.8
    addons:
      apt:
        sources:
          - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
        packages:
          - g++-4.8
  - '5':
  env:
    - CXX=g++-4.8
  addons:
    apt:
      sources:
        - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
      packages:
        - g++-4.8
  - '4':
  env:
    - CXX=g++-4.8
  addons:
    apt:
      sources:
        - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
      packages:
        - g++-4.8
script: 'npm install istanbul && node cli.js --coverage test/testsrc/es5-es6/a.js'
after_script: 'npm install coveralls && cat coverage/lcov.info | ./node_modules/.bin/coveralls'
notifications:
  email: false
  slack:
    rooms:
      - sumanjs:gvauyHhXXXXXcuzpV5QOAcI#general
```

I took this over to a YAML linter and it says:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not so weird. You have key `'7'` as the first key value pair of a mapping that is the first element of the sequence that is the value for the key `node_js` (i.e. the second occurence of that scalar in the file).

The indent for the key is four positions from the beginning of the line, so everything for the mapping it is part of should have at least that indentation.
`env:` however is not indented four positions, so that is an error.

If the value for key `'7'` is (an invisible ) `null` then indent `env` one more. If the value is a mapping that (among others) has a key `env`) then indent `env` at least two more positions.

Comment: thanks, I updated the question to make it more clear, I started off with valid yml, added some stuff and now it's invalid, still trying to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the right format to use was like so:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '7'
  - '6'
  - '5'
  - '4'
env:
  - CXX=g++-4.8
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
    packages:
      - g++-4.8

script: 'npm install istanbul && node cli.js --coverage test/testsrc/es5-es6/a.js'
after_script: 'npm install coveralls && cat coverage/lcov.info | ./node_modules/.bin/coveralls'
notifications:
  email: false
  slack:
    rooms:XXXXXXXXXzpV5v8LXXcI#travis-ci
```

If we wanted to apply the env/addons keys to the Node.js versions individually, however, I am not sure how that would work.

Comment: One thing is a correct YAML file, for that you had to further indent `env` like I indicated in my answer. Another thing is whether that YAML, once it can be loaded, is semantically correct input for Travis. I cannot really help you with the later part.

Comment: yeah that is true, I was personally missing information about both what is syntactically and semantically correct yaml for Travis, difficult situation. This seems to work for Travis, but I am not sure why the env/addon key/values are not separately defined for each Node.js version (4,5,6,7), so I am still in the dark semantically and syntactically, oh well :)